# How to write client code to allow logger injection

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-core

I am writing a .NetStandard application which is a thin wrapper around a web service / api. I will be consuming this client inside a .net core application. I would like to put logging into my client, but am unsure of what the best practices are.

I have achieved the desired result by allowing the consumer of the code to inject the logger via the constructor, but this seems messy and not best practice. I would previously use Common.Logging and then just code against the interface and allow the implementation to be provided at run-time, but I am unsure how to achieve the same with the new Microsoft.Extensions.Logging packages.

Also, I have a static method in a constructor-less class that would then not work with constructor injection at all.

```
public class MyClass {

    public ILogger _logger;

    public MyClass(ILogger Logger){
        _logger = Logger;
    }

    public void SomeMethod(){
        _logger.LogDebug("Called SomeMethod");
    }
}

public class SomeServiceClass {

    public static DoService(){
        _logger.LogDebug("Doing Service");
    }
}
```

I'm new to .net core, so maybe I am missing the point completely. Am I supposed to create a logger instance per class ( as with log4net ) or am i supposed to let the DI container create the loggers and then inject them somehow? Please can someone show me the correct way to handle this use case.

Comment: Constructor injection *is* how DI should be done most of the times, why exactly do you think it's messy?  Also, static classes go against DI, so don't expect best practices there

Comment: There is method or constructor injection, thats how DI works and one of SOLID principles... in this case, its ok to use ILogger instance through constructor because you dont expect from instance to change state in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyClass {

    public ILogger _logger;

    public MyClass(ILogger Logger){
        _logger = Logger;
    }

    public void SomeMethod(){
        _logger.LogDebug("Called SomeMethod");
    }
}
```

This class is entirely correct.

```
public class SomeServiceClass {

    public static DoService(){
        _logger.LogDebug("Doing Service");
    }
}
```

This class is smelly. Static methods are not very useful when trying to access the ServiceProvider that Net Core uses. I would consider changing this method to an extension method for a class that has the `_logger` exposed? Avoid the static methods for stuff like this.

An alternative approach could be to use a library I've written that allows AOP to be used in Net Core? (If the primary purpose is things like Logging)

https://github.com/f135ta/SimpleProxy